# El programa me muestra "0" en vez de los valores (C++)

Tags: c++, json, curl

mi codigo es personal para entrenar comprando y vendiendo cryptomonedas de manera que no deba usar mi dinero.

El usuario debe introducir una criptomoneda y el programa solicitara el precio actual de la moneda a la api de binance para simular la compra de la moneda, transcurrido un tiempo, el usuario puede presionar la tecla "Enter" para simular la venta de esa moneda... Al venderla, el programa arroja el nuevo precio actual de la moneda y la diferencia en porcentaje entre el precio de compra y el precio de venta.

el error que tiene es que el programa me muestra solo "0" de resultados. debe ser un error de conversion pero aún no logro arreglarlo.

El programa fue principalmente desarrollado por ChatGPT 3.5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <json/json.h>

using namespace std;

// Función para hacer la solicitud a la API de Binance
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
    string *response = (string*)userdata;
    response->append(ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main() {
    string symbol;
    cout << "Ingrese el nombre de la criptomoneda: ";
    cin >> symbol;
    string url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=" + symbol + "USDT";

    // Inicializar la biblioteca CURL para hacer solicitudes HTTP
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        // Configurar la solicitud HTTP
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        string response;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

        // Hacer la solicitud HTTP
        CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (result != CURLE_OK) {
            cerr << "Error al hacer la solicitud HTTP" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // Analizar la respuesta JSON
        Json::Value root;
        Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
        Json::CharReader *reader = builder.newCharReader();
        string errors;
        bool parsingSuccessful = reader->parse(
            response.c_str(), response.c_str() + response.size(), &root, &errors);
        if (!parsingSuccessful) {
            cerr << "Error al analizar la respuesta JSON" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // Obtener el precio actual de la moneda
        double price = root["price"].asDouble();
        cout << "El precio actual de " << symbol << " es: $" << price << endl;

        // Esperar a que el usuario presione una tecla
        cout << "Presione una tecla para obtener el precio nuevamente...";
        cin.ignore().get(); // Se agrega .get() para esperar a que el usuario presione una tecla

        // Obtener el precio nuevamente
        response.clear();
        result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (result != CURLE_OK) {
            cerr << "Error al hacer la solicitud HTTP" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // Analizar la respuesta JSON nuevamente
        parsingSuccessful = reader->parse(
            response.c_str(), response.c_str() + response.size(), &root, &errors);
        if (!parsingSuccessful) {
            cerr << "Error al analizar la respuesta JSON" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // Calcular el porcentaje de diferencia entre los precios
        double new_price = root["price"].asDouble();
        double percentage_change = (new_price - price) / price * 100;
        cout << "El nuevo precio de " << symbol << " es: $" << new_price << endl;
        cout << "La variación porcentual es: " << percentage_change << "%" << endl;

        // Liberar la memoria y cerrar la biblioteca CURL
        delete reader;
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Imagino que configuraste bien las librerías, no?

Comment: Deberías consultar el problema con chatGPT. ¿Quienes somos nosotros, meros humanos, para intentar develar los razonamientos de una IA?

Comment: No pidas ayuda a ChatGPT si tenés que hacer un código de cero. Esa herramienta es útil para programación solo si sabés lo que estás haciendo, porque está minado de ambigüedades, errores, y librerías desactualizadas. Dicho esto: aprendé a depurar el código, y mostrá en la pregunta tanto el resultado esperado como el obtenido.

Comment: el codigo que muestra el joven no es generado por ChatGPT, esta consumiendo el framework de la IA de ChatGPT v3.5 que es otra cosa...

Comment: Matias te recomiendo hacer un recorrido inverso y debug en paralelo para que valides en que punto hay un mal calculo. con los datos que diste a simple vista no se puede dar una respuesta y no tengo el setup de c++ para hacer pruebas o debug a tu codigo, que puede ser parcial y no logre hacerlo funcionar... tambien al final veo un return 0; que puede estar interviniendo

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 dice claramente que el codigo esta generado por IA. y no, no le pega a IA, le pega a binance.... el confundido fuiste vos...

Comment: Muchas gracias! si es verdad, esta lleno de ambiguedades pero no tengo mas opcion, a la vez voy aprendiendo de a poco los conceptos de programacion necesarios para mis proyectos, ya solucione el problema muchas gracias.